# Merge pandas dataframe with dataframe from csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a csv file where each row has a date yyyy-MM-dd and a count (e.g. 1, 2, 6).

```
2020-06-08,53
202-06-09,12
```

I read this into a dataframe as such and index on the date:

```py
import pandas as pd

data_df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=0, names=['date', 'count'])
data_df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(data_df['date'])
data_df = data_df.set_index('dt')
data_df.drop(['date'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

I then create a dataframe for a date range:

```py
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', end='12/31/2020', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['date'])
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index('dt')
df.drop(['date'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df['count'] = 0
```

Then I merged them:

```py
df.update(data_df)
```

When I print `df` it looks correct - it contains the default data, and where present in the csv, contains the actual count from the corresponding csv row.

I then use the calmap module (https://pythonhosted.org/calmap/) to generate a heatmap over the year:

```py
calmap.yearplot(df, year=2020, cmap='YlGn', daylabels='SMTWTFS', fig_kws=dict(figsize=(8, 4)))
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 4), indices imply (366, 4)
```

I am missing something obvious.  Most of the above code is lifted from somewhere.

Any help is appreciated.  I am pretty new to pandas and I am working through some tutorials but so far nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try pass `Series`

```
calmap.yearplot(df['count'], year=2020, cmap='YlGn', daylabels='SMTWTFS', fig_kws=dict(figsize=(8, 4)))
```

Comment: Thank you!  Also, turns out calmap doesn't work with pandas 1.x so I switched to calplot and I am moving along.  Thank you.